# how to add data from 2nd array to 1st array for showing chart in google Visualization api

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

```
var data = (['Date','first charts'],
            ['2013-12-17 Tue', 25],['2013-12-16 Mon', 39],
            ['2013-12-15 Sun', 58],['2013-12-14 Sat', 30],
            ['2013-12-13 Fri', 14],['2013-12-12 Thu', 69],
            ['2013-12-11 Wed', 5],['2013-12-10 Tue', 24],
            ['2013-12-09 Mon', 83],['2013-12-08 Sun', 38],
            ['2013-12-07 Sat', 58],['2013-12-06 Fri', 13],
            ['2013-12-05 Thu', 5],['2013-12-04 Wed', 24],
            ['2013-12-03 Tue', 44],['2013-12-02 Mon', 80],
            ['2013-12-01 Sun', 99],['2013-11-30 Sat', 19],
            ['2013-11-29 Fri', 74],['2013-11-28 Thu', 93],
            ['2013-11-27 Wed', 13],['2013-11-26 Tue', 4],
            ['2013-11-25 Mon', 7],['2013-11-24 Sun', 79],
            ['2013-11-23 Sat', 99],['2013-11-22 Fri', 82],
            ['2013-11-21 Thu', 54],['2013-11-20 Wed', 74],['2013-11-19 Tue', 93]);

var data2 = (['Date','Second charts'],['2013-12-17 Tue', 49],
            ['2013-12-16 Mon', 32],['2013-12-15 Sun', 88],
            ['2013-12-14 Sat', 43],['2013-12-13 Fri', 63],
            ['2013-12-12 Thu', 82],['2013-12-11 Wed', 54],
            ['2013-12-10 Tue', 73],['2013-12-09 Mon', 57],
            ['2013-12-08 Sun', 29],['2013-12-07 Sat', 32],
            ['2013-12-06 Fri', 4],['2013-12-05 Thu', 7],
            ['2013-12-04 Wed', 62],['2013-12-03 Tue', 98],
            ['2013-12-02 Mon', 18],['2013-12-01 Sun', 53],
            ['2013-11-30 Sat', 73],['2013-11-29 Fri', 93],
            ['2013-11-28 Thu', 48],['2013-11-27 Wed', 32],
            ['2013-11-26 Tue', 3],['2013-11-25 Mon', 23],
            ['2013-11-24 Sun', 81],['2013-11-23 Sat', 73],
            ['2013-11-22 Fri', 67],['2013-11-21 Thu', 42],
            ['2013-11-20 Wed', 62],['2013-11-19 Tue', 81]);
```

In google visualization api this data can be used as single charts. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Their is data of 2 charts. Each one is used for respect for one single data. I have 2 data. both data have same data. I want to simply make a array which hold data of these 2. How I can do it.

What I means currently I have

```
['2013-12-17 Tue', 25]
```

& from 2nd table

```
['2013-12-17 Tue', 49]
```

I want to get it as

```
['2013-12-17 Tue',25, 49]
```

I want to add the second value. all the date based on index will be same. How I can do this in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume the array notation is

```js
var data = [['Date','first charts'], ...
```

and not

```
var data = (['Date','first charts'], ...
```

You can import the "Second charts"-values to `data` like this :

```js
for (var i=0;i<data2.length;i++) {
    data[i].push(data2[i][1]);
}
```

So `data[1]` => `["2013-12-17 Tue", 25, 49]`

and then create the google visualization DataTable like this

```js
  var dataSet = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```

See the above in this working fiddle ->**http://jsfiddle.net/9aFTh/**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Actually I use my code for single charts before, so sytax I tried is used as function.call(["blah-date","blah"]);

Answer (score 0):

If you import those two data sets into DataTables, you can create a merged DataTable using the `google.visualization.data.join` function ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join)):

```
var dataTable1, dataTable2; // the two DataTables
// full join the two DataTables on dataTable1 column 0 to dataTable2 column 0
var mergedData = google.visualization.data.join(dataTable1, dataTable2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```